# The argument type 'File?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String?'. By trying to updatePhotoURL

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-authentication, flutter-dependencies

This error accur while I was trying to do `UserCredential;await auth.currentUser!.updatePhotoURL(image);` I don’t know If I done anything wrong I can’t figure it out . So if you know help. Thanks

```
late File? image;
```

Upload image from gallery:

```
getFromGallery() async {
    XFile? pickedFile = await ImagePicker().pickImage(
      source: ImageSource.gallery,
      maxWidth: 1800,
      maxHeight: 1800,
    );
    if (pickedFile != null) {
      setState(() {
        image = File(pickedFile.path);
      });
    }
  }
```

Here’s the function:

```
resetProfile(
    File? image,
    
  ) async {
    try {
      UserCredential;
      await auth.currentUser!.updatePhotoURL(image);
```

Button to called:

```
               ElevatedButton(
                      onPressed: () => resetProfile(image),
                      style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                        primary: Colors.grey,
                        onPrimary: Colors.black,
                        elevation: 0.0,
                        shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.zero,
                        ),
                      ),
                      child: const Text('Confirm'),
                    ),
```

Answer (score 0):

The error seems pretty clear: `updatePhotoURL` expects you to pass the URL of the image you want to set for the user, but you are trying to pass a `File` to it.

If you want to use the local for file the user, you'll first need to upload it somewhere, get a URL to that place, and then pass *that* URL to `updatePhotoURL`. One place you can upload such images would be into Cloud Storage through Firebase, as shown here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/ios/upload-files

Answer (score 0):

You are directly passing the file inside a String. Get the download URL of an image and pass it inside the updatePhotoImage URL. This will work.

Comment: Do you have like any link to that EX.